# jQuery - Adding data values dynamically and retrieving data from database

Tags: jquery, html

I have some images on my website, which when clicked shows the "`.TutorialsSlideDown`" div and at the same time hides the "`.tutorial_listing`" div. I'd like to add data attributes to these images, and then checking which one was clicked, and according to that populate the ".TutorialsSlideDown" div with data from my database.

Can this be done this way? How? If not, what's the best way?

HTML:

```
 <div class="tutorial_listing">
        <img id="PhpTutorials" src="~/Images/PHP.png" width="150px" height="150px" alt="PHP Tutorialok"/>
        <img id="AspdotNetWPTutorials" src="~/Images/ASPdotNet.png" width="150px" height="150px" alt="ASP.NET Tutorialok"/>
    </div>
    <div class="tutorial_listing"><h3>Programozás</h3></div>
    <div class="TutorialsSlideDown"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#PhpTutorials').click(function () { openTutorials("PHP Tutorialok. <a class='GoBack'>Vissza</a>") });
    $('#AspdotNetWPTutorials').click(function () { openTutorials("ASP.NET Web Pages Tutorialok. <a class='GoBack'>Vissza</a>") });

    function openTutorials(title) {

        $('.tutorial_listing').slideUp(400);
        $('.TutorialsSlideDown').slideDown(400);
        $('#PageTitle').html(title);
        $('.GoBack').bind('click', function () {
            $('.TutorialsSlideDown').slideUp(400);
            $('.tutorial_listing').slideDown(400);
            $('#PageTitle').html("Tutorialok");
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add an extra variable to the function which has the ID of the tutorial in the database
2. Make an ajax call to a server-side script which can handle the get/post and take the ID
3. Query the database and get the information you want
4. Return the data and embed it into the page with jQuery

I don't think there's much sense writing the entire code for you.  This is a guide that should push you in the right direction.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

You can read about the jQuery ajax here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: tip: provide external links ;)

Comment: @Vogel612 Do you mean to websites with tutorials and / or links to the jquery ajax page?

Comment: best would be both i guess, but usually the jquery.ajax page will suffice ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I haven't thought of that.